# Textured and Non-Textured Rendering Time?

Tags: opengl, graphics, 3d, unity-game-engine, opengl-es-2.0

Weather a Textured Model render faster than than a non textured one ? What I think is NO?
What could be difference, small or too high.

I am creating a game for OpenGL enabled devices. I want to reduce my draw calls and rendering time. Should I prefer non-textured only colored models ?

Comment: this should not be a technical concern but one of visual design - do you want your game to have an old-school flat-colored look or not?

Comment: @LearnCocos2D, yes I want it to be flat, I don't want to put large details, theirfore wondering will that help to increase performance.

Comment: In that case you don't need textures, so don't use them unless you want to add details that you can only add by using textures. It's not really a relevant performance decision, plus even if non-textured models were slower the app would use a lot of memory, so there's always a trade-off.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no reasonable scenario where textured rendering would be faster, and it may very well be slower. It all depends on where your bottlenecks are.

Fundamentally, when you use texturing, you have texture sampling operations in your (fragment) shader. These operations are typically executed by dedicated hardware units, which have limited throughput. Just as importantly, they obviously have to access the texture data, which can easily become a bottleneck, depending on many factors:

- If your fragment processing is the bottleneck in the first place. While that's very common, graphics applications can also be CPU limited, or be limited by other parts of the graphics pipeline.
- Overall complexity of the fragment shader. If there are a lot of other time consuming operations, a texture sampling operation will make much less of a relative difference.
- How well texture sampling can be overlapped with other shader operations.
- Locality of the texture access. Texture sampling uses caches, and cache efficiency depends on the access patterns, where localized access is normally better than scattered access.
- Size of the texture.
- If mipmapping is used.
- Hardware performance characteristics.

But generally, you shouldn't use texturing if there's no good need for it. Particularly if the shaders are simple, and the textures large, memory bandwidth from sampling can easily become the bottleneck in the rendering pipeline.

Where things get more interesting is if there's a tradeoff between using texturing and more computation in the shader. For example, for some relatively complex lighting methods, you have the option to use precomputed results stored in textures, or to do the full calculation in the shader every time. Those kinds of cases need to be benchmarked. Modern GPUs have an enormous amount of raw horsepower, and executing a few more operations may well be more efficient than a texture access.

Comment: Good answer. You could add "Whether the texture coordinates are dependent (calculated in the shader) or not" to your list.

Answer (score 2):

unless you are tapping into **GLSL** then from device perspective it is the same (at least for modern devices).

There should be no difference between textured and untextured rendering speed of coarse there must be enough texture units, gfx memory resources available. If not then texturing will kill the performance. This happens when you use bigger textures then your gfx can handle and must swapping between shared computer memory and gfx card.

What can affect the performance is not the rendering itself but the gl calls. For example if you use the old stuff like `glTexCoord` then the individual calls is what is slow. Use arrays or **VBO/VAO** objects if you can instead that will improve performance **greatly**.

One common beginner bug is to load the texture into gfx before each use instead of leave it in card. I sow this many times ... and even I was doing it when I was a beginner. To activate the texture just use `glBind(...)` call and may be set few parameters of the texture unit if needed but load the texture into memory just **ONCE**.

What is important while rendering is trying to switch textures least times possible so render/group all geometries using the same texture together if possible. Some **3D** mesh file formats are written for this purpose usually there is single texture for whole object so no unnecessary texture context switching is needed. This is also why texture atlases are faster with the draw back of lower quality. In modern **OpenGL** there is also bind-less texturing now which get rid of the `glBind` call for good at cost of additional memory for texture id parameter.